# How to set the resolution of a non-interactive window station on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, screen-resolution

I'm launching an application from a windows service in a non-interactive window station in order to take a screenshot of the application running.

The application runs 'full screen' at the resolution of the non-interactive window station which defaults to `1024x768`, I would like to increase this resolution to something higher.

I can read the current resolution by calling `EnumDisplaySettings` but calls to `ChangeDisplaySettings` to set the resolution fail returning `DISP_CHANGE_FAILED`

Is it possible to change the resolution of a non-interactive window station?

Comment: *"calls to `ChangeDisplaySettings` to set the resolution fail."* - Fails how? What error code do you get? Since a non-interactive window station may not have a default display device, have you tried calling [ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183413.aspx) instead?

Comment: The calls to `ChangeDisplaySettings` to which we are passing flag `CDS_TEST` returns `DISP_CHANGE_FAILED`, but `GetLastError` returns zero.

Comment: The return value of `GetLastError` is meaningless; the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183411.aspx) doesn't say, that the thread's last error code is set.

Comment: Calls to `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` exhibits the same behaviour, but calling `EnumDisplayDevices` does not return any devices.

Comment: It's a non-interactive station. What are you expecting?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No expectations, but given that a non-interactive session does have a resolution set I'm just asking if it's possible to programmatically change it?

Comment: `DISP_CHANGE_FAILED` means driver failed the resolution change. So you'd want to investigate why the driver failed the change. One possibility is to use OSR's IRPTRACKER to capture the IRP(s) that failed. Another is to use ETW to trace the driver (if driver supports it). Note that "driver" doesn't necessarily mean code that came from a third party, it could be code from MS. For example if 3rd party code is a miniport, then the rest of the driver (the "port" part) comes from MS. If the MS part failed request it could be because the operation is deliberately not supported.